# How to extract inner array to multidimensional array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, extract

I'm trying to get the content of files and put in array. The files are named with date, but in one file it might have multiple price. I used explode function to split the string and put in array. The problem I face is dont know how to extract the inner array to outer array and keep other key values.

```
foreach( $paths as $item => $wishlist ){
   foreach( $wishlist as $k => $v ){
      $file = basename($v);
      $info = pathinfo($file);
      $file_name = basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
      $array[$k]['date'] = $file_name;
      $array[$k]['fruit'] = $v;
      $content = nl2br(file_get_contents($v));
      $words = explode($file_name, $content);
      $array[$k]['price'] = $words;
   }
}
```

The multidimensional array should keep the date and fruit value based on the extracted prices.

```
Current Output:

[{"date":"2023-06-01", "fruit":"apple", "price":["2", "4", "6"] },
{"date":"2023-06-02", "fruit":"orange", "price":["5", "7"] },
{"date":"2023-06-03", "fruit":"mango", "price":["11", "12", "8"] }]

Expected Output:

[{"date":"2023-06-01", "fruit":"apple", "price": "2" },
{"date":"2023-06-01", "fruit":"apple", "price": "4" },
{"date":"2023-06-01", "fruit":"apple", "price": "6" },
{"date":"2023-06-02", "fruit":"orange", "price": "5" },
{"date":"2023-06-02", "fruit":"orange", "price": "7" },
{"date":"2023-06-03", "fruit":"mango", "price": "11" },
{"date":"2023-06-03", "fruit":"mango", "price": "12" },
{"date":"2023-06-03", "fruit":"mango", "price": "8" }]
```

Please help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first glance I guess you could try to change you code into something like this:

```php
foreach($paths as $item =>$wishlist){
    foreach($wishlist as $k=>$v){
        $file = basename($v);
        $info = pathinfo($file);
        $file_name = basename($file, '.'.$info['extension']);
        $content = nl2br(file_get_contents($v));
        $words = explode($file_name, $content);
        foreach($words as $word){
            $array[] = [
                'date'=>$file_name,
                'fruit'=>$v,
                'price'=>$word
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

though not seeing much before the code you posted; it could be useful to have a little bit more context, like the form of the array you're passing, and having the code directly written in your question instead of an image :)
Anyway, as said this should do the trick, but I would advise you to optimize it a little bit, later on (also depending on how big the array you're going to pass is)

Comment: Edited. Not familiar with the posting because its my first time using StackOverflow.  And based on your suggestion I'm able to put the price in outer array. But why the array will return three time ? The last return array return all the elements which is the array that I need, how to remove the first two array?

Comment: Yes of course, just saying so you know for the next times using it :) Anyway, if you could post an example dump of the input array I could provide more precise code for your use case, since mine was based only on the results you were showing. providing details on the array you need to transform would be really helpful